# Word Count in a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, counter

I have a data set with around 4000 client questions. I want to know about the topics which the client has asked the most about. I don't have the topic list with me. I want to get a word count of ever word in the column.

The data is in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Can you add some sample data, expected output and what you try? All is missing and it is reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by whitespace and `expand=True` for `DataFrame`, reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and get sorted counts by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['aa ss d','f d aa aa','aa']})
print (df)
           a
0    aa ss d
1  f d aa aa
2         aa

s = df['a'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
print (s)
aa    4
d     2
f     1
ss    1
dtype: int64
```

For `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df['a'].str.split(expand=True)
              .stack()
              .value_counts()
              .rename_axis('vals')
              .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
  vals  count
0   aa      4
1    d      2
2    f      1
3   ss      1
```